# How to call a scala function with parameters using java classloader?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, urlclassloader

I am looking for some guidance to load the scala jar into the java classloader.
Below function works for me when I use a java jar file.

where, arr is an Array of java.net.URL for all the jars that I need to load into the classloader.

```
val classLoader = new URLClassLoader(arr, this.getClass().getClassLoader())
val clazz = classLoader.loadClass(className)
val myMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, classOf[String])
myMethod.setAccessible(true)
val response = myMethod.invoke(methodName)
```

However, when I am trying to use similar method to call a scala function from a scala jar file, I get classNotFound Exception at *val clazz = classLoader.loadClass(className)* at this line.

```
val clazz = classLoader.loadClass("com.testing.Test")
```

I want to call print method of class Test. Can someone please guide? I checked couple of other posts in SO, but they are dealing with objects and traits which may not be applicable for my use case.

Scala class for example:

```
package com.testing
    class Test(){
      def print (a: String, b: String): String = {
       return a+b
      }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think your Scala class example is wrong. This is not possible `("a": String, "b": String)`.

Comment: Sorry for that, updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer for someone looking for a similar issue.
Classloader does work as expected for both scala and java.

For Java, just passing the method name in method.invoke worked for me, while in scala I had to specifically create an object of class and pass that object to method.invoke. A new learning for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should work same as for Java classes, because there's no difference classloaders should care about, I've done this plenty of times. But a possible problem is if you don't include dependencies in `arr`; this is true for both Java and Scala, but for Scala you may be missing `scala-library-<version>.jar`.

Comment: Hi Alexey, I already added scala-library-2.11.11.jar and thats the same version on my scala project.

Comment: can you please share a sample code so that I can see what I am missing? This is the error message I am getting
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.testing.Test
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: All my examples would be inside big projects and not really useful. You can see an example at https://github.com/scalan/scalan/blob/b08d8cc299c498646950a929aaaa3affb7c5579f/lms-backend/core/src/main/scala/scalan/compilation/lms/scalac/LmsCompilerScala.scala: it just does `classLoader.loadClass` same as yours.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but it bypassed my code now and now its failing in next line.     val myMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, classOf[String])

. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Comment: Is there something wrong with the scala class or do I need to use object?

Comment: I think I figured out the solution.
val foo = clazz.newInstance() and passing foo in mymethod.invoke(foo) resolved. I will check again to see it doesn't break.

Comment: Hi Alexey, The program ran correctly for a single function, for multiple functions in scala - spark, this started giving error like "{className}$$anonfun$1" where {className} is the actual classname

Comment: Seems like issue with the spark. I think the method is working as expected.